# Use photoshop in command window hiddenly

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-script

Is there a way to use Photoshop to convert image from command line.

for example :

Photoshop.exe -convert c:/img1.tif c:/img1.png

I want to run this command from command line, without opening Photoshop application.
I don't want to see Photoshop window.

Answer (score 1):

```
Photoshop.exe -convert c:/img1.tif c:/img1.png
```

Won't actually do anything. Photoshop Scripts work in three flavours; Visual Basic, JavaScript and Applescript. There are no commands to "convert" between file types. You can write a script to save a .tiff to a .png BUT it will involve opening the Photoshop application.

I think you're actually after [imageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) - which can do conversions like the one above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ImageMagick`, which is available for Windows from [here](http://imagemagick.org). The command you want is `convert` like this:

```
convert c:\img1.tif c:\img1.png
```